# IPFW interface with special character

Tags: freebsd, vlan, ipfw

I'm new using FreeBSD and IPFW, but in my work we need to change from GNU/Linux, using IPtables, to FreeBSD and IPFW to packege filter. We have some rules in IPtables script that we need to put on IPFW. Almost all rules are working fine, but there are some special character that not.

Here the problem:

On GNU/Linux we have a lots of VLAN named team1.3900, team1.3901... and so on. In the IPtables script we put all together like this: clientes=team1.+ 
The IPtables work fine with this kind of variable, but I tried to to the same think with the IPFW and is not working. If I use the interface properly the rule works.

Here the output of one rule line of my FreeBSD IPFW:

allow ip from 192.168.0.0/24 to any out via team1.+
allow ip from any to 192.168.0.0/24 out via team1.+

Like that above not work, but if I chante to

allow ip from 192.168.0.0/24 to any out via team1.3901
allow ip from any to 192.168.0.0/24 out via team1.3901

works fine.

Is possible to use this kind of special character or I need to set all my VLAN's interfaces?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to arround the problem I changed the team1.+ to team1.* and it is working know. I will make more tests but what we need, until know, its working.

Best regards.